# Can the Cloud SQL Python Connector be used with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

So I have been trying to deploy an App Engine Standard app using flask, sqlalchemy and Cloud SQL. I believed I had finished all the coding and was ready to deploy when I found out that connecting with the techniques described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/samples/cloud-sql-mysql-sqlalchemy-create-tcp?hl=es-419) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763171/can-sqlalchemy-be-used-with-google-cloud-sql) simply don't work when deployed on an App Engine instance. So after [asking some things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535258/connect-app-engine-flask-sqlalchemy-to-cloud-sql/67577721), I believe I have been able to stablish a connection between my app and the SQL instance in the Cloud SQL server using the newly released [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector/0.1.0/), but I don't how to further use that connection along the SQLAlchemy library.

For example, see my (relevant) code:

**config.py**

```
"""Flask configuration."""
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.cloud.sql.connector import connector

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))

DB_USERNAME = environ.get('DB_USERNAME')
DB_PASSWORD = environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
DB_ADDRESS = environ.get('DB_ADDRESS')
DB_PORT = environ.get('DB_PORT')
DB_NAME = environ.get('DB_NAME')
DB_CONNECTION_STRING = environ.get('DB_CONNECTION_STRING')
        
class Config:
    """Base config."""
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
    TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    connector.connect(
        DB_CONNECTION_STRING, 
        "pymysql",
        user=DB_USERNAME,
        password=DB_PASSWORD,
        db=DB_NAME
    )
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import random
import string
import datetime
import json
import re
from config import MAPBOX_TOKEN

#Create App
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.DevConfig')
    return app

app = create_app()
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# User ORM for SQLAlchemy
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, nullable = False)
    ptoken = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable = False, unique = True)
    geodict = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
```

And while the `connector.connect` thingy from Google works appropriately, when the code above is run I get the following warning:

```
..\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
```

To fix this issue I have tried some silly things like:

```
class Config:
    """Base config."""
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
    TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = connector.connect(
        DB_CONNECTION_STRING, 
        "pymysql",
        user=DB_USERNAME,
        password=DB_PASSWORD,
        db=DB_NAME
    )
```

But this obviously doesn't work and I just can't find any helpful info online.

So my question is: Can the Cloud SQL Python Connector be used with SQLAlchemy? How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It isn't listed on the SQLAlchemy [dialects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/index.html) page, so I don't think it can be used at present.  I would imagine that it's unlikely to get supported until it's GA; currently it seems to be alpha.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, connecting from App Engine to Cloud SQL works just fine. [There's an entire page about doing it on in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard).

Second, the connector can be used an alternative to that method. [Here is an example of it being used with SQL Alchemy.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/tests/system/test_pg8000_connection.py#L30-L42)

Answer (score 0):

What you were looking for is documented here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/README.md#flask-sqlalchemy

The key information is that you can use `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` to provide the connector factory function to the SqlAlchemy instance managed by Flask-SqlAlchemy.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes


# initialize Python Connector object
connector = Connector()

# Python Connector database connection function
def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
        "project:region:instance-name", # Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name
        "pg8000",
        user="my-user",
        password="my-password",
        db="my-database",
        ip_type= IPTypes.PUBLIC  # IPTypes.PRIVATE for private IP
    )
    return conn


app = Flask(__name__)

# configure Flask-SQLAlchemy to use Python Connector
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql+pg8000://"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    "creator": getconn
}

# initialize the app with the extension
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
```