# Google cloud app engine, flask and sqlalchemy main.py setup

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to deploy a Flask Web app using Google Cloud App Engine Standard. I currently am using a google cloud sql, mysql database and am connecting to it using sqlalchemy. My Flask web app is setup like this.

```
.
├── main.py
├── app.yaml
├── auth.py
├── views.py
├── models.py
├── views.py
├── requirements.txt
│   ├── static
│   │   └── styles.css
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── other html files
```

To set up my full website I use a main.py file that looks like this

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from flask_login import LoginManager


db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRET KEY'

PASSWORD = "CLOUDSQL PASSWORD"

PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS = "CLOUDSQL PUBLIC IP"

DBNAME = "CLOUDSQL DATABASE NAME"

PROJECT_ID = "GCLOUD PROJECT ID"

INSTANCE_NAME = "CLOUDSQL INSTANCE NAME"

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"mysql+mysqldb://root:{PASSWORD}@{PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}/{DBNAME}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{PROJECT_ID}:{INSTANCE_NAME}"

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True
db.init_app(app)

from models import User

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

from views import views
from auth import auth

app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
    app.logger.info('Main is Working')
```

When I run this locally it seems to work just fine, but when trying to run it on google app engine standard it just infinitely loads. Does anyone know what I must change to fix this. Also ignore the middle of the page imports of views and auth. They are there to allow the database to be built before trying to import them as they incorporate the database.

Comment: It seems like you missed adding a [`Cloud SQL Auth Proxy`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-auth-proxy). Check with this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67577721/18265702) which suggest that `Cloud SQL Auth Proxy` option will allow you to easily connect without having to add your IP address to the allowlist and the database connection parameters should be the same both locally and deployed.

Comment: Also check the `App Engine service logs` to get a better understanding of why the app running is just infinitely loading.